# spinning a line in javafx 2.0

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

how to spin line (rotating 360 degree) in java fx? here the code :

```
package javafxapplication1;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse;
import javafx.scene.shape.EllipseBuilder;
import javafx.scene.shape.LineTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.transform.Transform;

public class JavaFXApplication1 extends Application { 
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}



@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
  Group root = new Group();
  Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600, Color.WHITE);

  Ellipse lingkaran = EllipseBuilder.create()
    .centerX(400)
    .centerY(300)
    .radiusX(210)
    .radiusY(210)   
    .strokeWidth(3)
    .stroke(Color.BLACK)
    .fill(Color.WHITE)
    .build();

  Path path = new Path();
  MoveTo moveTo = new MoveTo();
  moveTo.setX(400);
  moveTo.setY(300);

  LineTo lineTo = new LineTo();
  lineTo.setX(400);
  lineTo.setY(100);

  path.getElements().add(moveTo);
  path.getElements().add(lineTo);
  path.setStrokeWidth(5);
  path.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

  root.getChildren().add(lingkaran);
  root.getChildren().add(path);

  primaryStage.setScene(scene);
  primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

i want to spin the line 360 degree, but i don't know how to do it. I have been looking for this in google but i never found the solution. Can somebody help me please?

Comment: Check JavaFX [Ensemble](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/samples/index.html) sample. There is Rotate Transition (animation) example.

Comment: if in the c we know we can change the cordinate using
for(x = 1; x < 20; x++)
  gotoxy(x,12)
ho about in java fx?

Comment: for your approach it would be `lineTo.setX(x); lineTo.setY(y);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could rotate your circle and line with:

```
root.getChildren().add(lingkaran);
root.getChildren().add(path);

RotateTransition rot = RotateTransitionBuilder.create().node(root)
    .byAngle(360).duration(new Duration(3000)).build();
rot.play();

primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
```

If you want to rotate only the line, replace `.node(root)` with `.node(path).`. If you don't want to use an animation you may set the rotation property of the line.